# how do i fix the qt extension for visual studio?

Tags: c++, qt

i have installed qt for open source users and the qt extension for visual studio code. At first I was able to create projects but they will not match the real paths to the corresponding libraries / header files, and after doing so it will give me a qmaker error. After uninstalling and reinstalling the extension and qt I find myself unable to even set the correct path to the qt folder. When I try to do so it prompts me with an error : Error reading VS project settings. I have tried removing then adding the  msvc2017_64 component but to no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall your qt extension, and try to download [qt-vsaddin](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/) according to your vs version. After installing the extension, you can add new qt version in the same way.
PS: Re-downloading qt extension in visual studio is useless (I have met the same problem like you)
Hope to help you